# Convert string 'yyyy-mm' to date object

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL table, I have a column with just 'yyyy-mm', how can I covert into a Date object and compare if it is older than 2 months from now?

When I try this, `CONVERT` fails because the [Month] format is just `yyyy-mm' without the day

```
where DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(DATE, [Month]),GETDATE()) < 60
```

I am using SQL Server.

I have tried the answer from the comment

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS aCount
  FROM [MyTable]
  where [name] != 'abc'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [Month] + '-01')
```

But I get error saying

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(DATE, [Month] + '-01'),GETDATE()) < 60`? But how do you expect to know if the date is older than 2 months if you don't know if its the 1st or the 31th of that date?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. it should be getting the start of the month of current day and compare the each row in the Table and see if it is older than 2 months.  I am looking into how to get start of the month of current day of today in SQL too.

Comment: Start of this month: `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1)` or `DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1));`

Comment: @n179911a you should edit your question to add that second requeriment so you can get a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Also be careful because `yyyy-MM-dd` can be misinterpreted as `yyyy-dd-MM` (just try with `SET LANGUAGE British;`). A safer string format is `yyyyMMdd` without the dashes, but could be avoided altogether by storing a date (with the right data type) in the first place.